# Java boolean return types

Tags: java, boolean, return

I'm confused by this code, I thought for a boolean you must return 'true' or 'false' and nothing else so why does this code work?

```
public static boolean diagonal(Location l, Location l1) {
    return l.getX() != l1.getX() && l.getY() != l1.getY();
}
```

Comment: that is returning a boolean, its checking if the x value for l doesnt equal the x value for l1, and the same for the y values

Comment: `boolean` is a *type*. Types can be thought of as a container for *values*. `true` and `false` are the only two values that inhabit the `boolean` type. Expressions (calculations) have types, which as long as that type is not `void`, means they have a value. (`void` is the type that has no values.) Your function says "I will return a `boolean` type". Your expression, comprised of subexpressions, returns a `boolean` as explained in the answers. (That is to say, it returns a value that fits in the `boolean` type, either `true` or `false`.) So it all checks out.

Answer (score 3):

The `!=` and `&&` operators evaluate to a `boolean` result. They each perform a test and evaluate to the boolean values `true` or `false` depending on the results of the test (the first tests inequality, the second is a logical AND).

See [JLS 15.21](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21) for a description of equality operators and what they evaluate to. In particular:

> The type of an equality expression is always `boolean`.

See [JLS 15.23](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23) for a description of the conditional AND operator and what it evaluates to. In particular:

> The type of a conditional-and expression is always `boolean`.

Also try this:

```
System.out.println(5 != 5);
System.out.println(5 != 6);
System.out.println(true && false);
System.out.println(true && true);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is returning a `boolean`.  If `l.getX()` "does not equal" `l1.get(X)` "and" `l.getY()` "does not equal" `l1.get(y)`, then "return true" otherwise "return false".

`!=` and `&&` are binary operators that each return a `boolean`.

Comment: Thanks alot, well explained

Comment: @user2997839 Since you're new to SO, here take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 0):

because

```
return l.getX() != l1.getX() && l.getY() != l1.getY();
```

is a boolean expression and return statement would do the result

this is equivalent if you express the order

```
return ((l.getX() != l1.getX()) && (l.getY() != l1.getY()));
```

true or false it depends on result of the evaluation, and finally it return a boolean because only boolean operations performed.

```
boolean a = l.getX() != l1.getX(); 
boolean b = l.getY() != l1.getY();
boolean c = a && b;

return c;
```

Comment: true or false it depends on result of the evaluation

Answer (score 0):

It is returning true or false.

```
l.getX() != l1.getX() && l.getY() != l1.getY();
```

Is a statement that checks if 1.get(X) is not equal to l1.getX() AND 1.get(Y) is not equal to l1.getY().